# Simplest caffe network for image classification

Tags: caffe

I have a set of 60000 train and 10000 test images (227x227). The images are either completely black (label 1), or black with a white patch in the middle (label 255). What would be the simplest caffe network that I can train on this data to get accuracy 95% or higher. I need to deploy this on an embedded device so the simplest network is what I desire.

I tried to train it using the BVLC reference caffenet and got an accuracy of 99.6%. I converted this model into CMSISNN to deploy it on a ARM device but it generated a weights file of 150MB which is not feasible for an embedded device.

Comment: If all you want to distinguish is a fully black image from one that isn't fully black, then ML might be overkill. Wouldn't it be simpler to average the luminance of the whole image and just have a cutoff value from where on you consider it non-black?

Comment: Yes that would be correct, but this is to get the ML framework up and running on my embedded device to run more advanced ML algorithms. Though I have successfully run the CMSISNN image recognition  example on my device, the above exercise will help me verify an end to end solution.. From train in caffe to inferring on the embedded device.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SqueezeNet](https://github.com/forresti/SqueezeNet/tree/master/SqueezeNet_v1.1) (4.7 MB, >= 80.3% top-5 on ImageNet), or [MobileNet](https://github.com/shicai/MobileNet-Caffe) (v2: 13.5 MB, 90.49% top-5 on ImageNet) as baselines. Since you have a much simpler problem, you might want to try a super simple network with your own topology.